# Set Wallpaper from gallery according to position

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-gallery, wallpaper

I have a Gallery and an imageView as in this pic: http://i50.tinypic.com/2e6h2so.png
and i need button1 to set the current image as wallpaper
I am having a problem in setResource

```
    myWallpaperManager.setResource(mImageIds[position]);
```

This is my code:

```
  public class batman extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
  Button set;
  private int[] mImageIds = {
    R.drawable.b,
    R.drawable.b1,
    R.drawable.b2,
    R.drawable.b3,
    R.drawable.b4,
    R.drawable.b5,
    R.drawable.b6,
    R.drawable.b7,
    R.drawable.b8,
    R.drawable.b9,
    R.drawable.b10,
    R.drawable.b11,
    R.drawable.b12,
    R.drawable.b13,
    R.drawable.b14,
    R.drawable.b15,
    R.drawable.b16,
    R.drawable.b17,
    R.drawable.b18,
    R.drawable.b19,
    R.drawable.b20,
    R.drawable.b21,
    R.drawable.b22,
    R.drawable.b23,
    R.drawable.b24,  

  };

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.batman);

    set=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    set.setOnClickListener(this);
    Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
    g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick
        (AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {


        ImageView imageView =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageView.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
      }
    });
  }

  public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    int mGalleryItemBackground;
    private Context mContext;


    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
      mContext = c;
      TypedArray a = c.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.GalleryA);
      mGalleryItemBackground = a.getResourceId(
                                               R.styleable.GalleryA_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
      a.recycle();
    }

    public int getCount() {
      return mImageIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
      return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
      return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);

      i.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
      i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 100));
      i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
      i.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);

      return i;
    }
  }

  public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int id=arg0.getId();
    if(id==R.id.button1)
    {
      WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager
        = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
      try {
        myWallpaperManager.setResource(mImageIds[position]);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need this permission in your manifest:

```
 “android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER”

ImageAdapter i = (ImageAdapter)parent.getAdapter();
Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),(int)i.getItemId(position));
WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
try {
myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(mBitmap);
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wallpaper set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error setting wallpaper", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
});
}
```

Comment: parent and position are underlined with red ??
they cannot be resolved

Comment: I think so, find it here the full source http://chengalva.com/2012/11/07/android-how-to-set-a-custom-wall-paper-from-a-list-of-images-in-a-gridview/ its gridview but its so easy to use it with  a gallery widget

Comment: Do you have apps ?? can you send a link

Comment: What do you mean by apps ?

Comment: android applications on play store ?

Answer (score 0):

First You have to add the `SET_WALLPAPER` permission to your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
</manifest>
```

And then change your `Button ClickListener` as below:

> ```
>   ImageAdapter image = (ImageAdapter)parent.getAdapter();
>   Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),mImageIds[pos]); <----Try by changing this line.
>   WallpaperManager m_manager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
>   try {
>         m_manager.setBitmap(mBitmap);
>        }
>     catch (IOException e)
>        {}
>     }
>   });
>  }
> ```

Comment: Hey i have done some changes in my code. Please check out and try out. If it doesn't work then please let me know. Thanks.